# Ruby on Rails - How to add an n:m association in a generic method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generics

Say two models are in a has_and_belong_to_many relation e.g. driver & car 
In Rails you can add a new relationship by using

```
driver.cars << car
```

Now, how to make this line generic?
In the controller the method call hands over an instance of driver, a string indicating the associative class 'cars' and an array of car ids to be added.

```
add_association(@driver, 'car', [car_ids])
```

And the method looks like this.

```
  def add_association(object, association_class_name, ids)
    model = association_class_name.constantize
    associations = association_class_name.pluralize

    ids.each do |incoming_id|
      association = model.find_by_id(incoming_id)
      if association.nil?
        return false
      else
        object.associations << association # throws NoMethodError: undefined method `associations' for #<Driver:0x...
      end
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

User **public_send** method like this:

```
def add_association(object, association_class_name, ids)
  model = association_class_name.constantize
  associations = association_class_name.underscore.pluralize

  ids.each do |incoming_id|
    association = model.find_by_id(incoming_id)
    if association.nil?
      return false
    else
      object.public_send associations << association 
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: [public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send)

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: i didn't know public_send thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it does expect a method and driver.cars is more like an array of related objects. It does not do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, @driver.cars is an array of objects of Car class. So you can add car object in that particular array.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can give precedence in operations like this;   (object.public_send associations) << association